# Generate the initial id value of each repeated records

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a table with column A,B,C

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 |  | 100 |
| 101 | 100 | 100 |
| 102 | 101 | 100 |
| 103 |  | 103 |
| 104 | 103 | 103 |

In the above example, we have 5 records.

- First records of column A has no repeated, so column B is null.
- Second record of column A value 101 is repeated of first record and then column B value 100.
- Third record of column A value 102 is repeated of second record and column B value 101.
- Fourth has record of column A has no repeated, so column B is null.
- Fivth record of column A value 104 is the repeated of fourth record and then column B values is 103

With above data C column need to populate based on the column of initial value of column A.
B column data have the repeated of previous value A.
C column  value populate based on A and it get repeated of column B.

I need to populate column C, value will be initial value of it repeated record. Need to create a SQL query

Comment: A B C
100  100
101 100 100
102 101 100
103  103
104 103 103

Comment: The logic is very unclear, can you please give more examples? For example _"Second record of column A value 101 is repeated of first record"_ makes not much sense since the provided data has "previous" value of 100 so no repetition here.